# How to label values in a column based on a dataframe "dictionary"

Tags: r, label, r-labelled

I have data like this

```
col1
33
924
33
12
924
```

and a dataframe like this

```
col1   col2
12     "London"
33     "Paris"
924    "Singapore"
```

How do I label the first dataframe based on the columns in the second dataframe using r's labelled?

I know that using val_labels() I can apply a value label to values in a column using:

```
val_labels(df$col1) <- c(London = 12, Paris = 33, Singapore = 924)
```

But I have 1000 different values and need an approach that allows me to use a dataframe to do it.

Comment: `labelled` package is used to label variables (columns), not rows

Comment: @Waldi check out val_labels() in labelled

Comment: What do you want? Just get a col2 in your first data.frame with the city names?

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg I have to export it after to spss that works with value labels and it is helpful to use labels for data analysis, because the data analysis tools don't work with strings but can use labels to assign names in the figures so I don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, though there are likely more elegant solutions:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(33, 924, 33, 12, 924))
dic <- data.frame(col1 = c(12, 33, 924),
                  col2 = c("London","Paris","Singapore"))

library(labelled)
ct <- 1
for(i in dic$col1){
  val_label(df, i) <- as.character(dic[ct,2])
  ct <- ct+1
}
str(df)
# > str(df)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  1 variable:
#   $ col1: dbl+lbl [1:5]  33, 924,  33,  12, 924
# ..@ labels: Named num  12 33 924
# .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "London" "Paris" "Singapore"
# >
```

Answer (score 0):

With `val_labels`:

```r
library(labelled)

col1=c(33,924,33,12,924)

ref <- read.table(text='
col1   col2
12     "London"
33     "Paris"
924    "Singapore"',header=T)

val_labels(col1)<-setNames(ref$col1,ref$col2)

col1
#> <labelled<double>[5]>
#> [1]  33 924  33  12 924
#> 
#> Labels:
#>  value     label
#>     12    London
#>     33     Paris
#>    924 Singapore
```

Comment: I get this error: Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't convert `labels` <character> to match type of `x` <integer>.

Comment: do you get the error with the above dataset, or on other data? This is working fine for me on `R 4.1.0` with `reprex` package

Comment: what is `class(col1)` for you, `integer` as in my code or `character`? both `col1` should have the same datatype

Comment: They are both integer. I couldn't get it to work, but your solution works for the data I provided, so I can't ask for more.